# Can't access django imports in my python project

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am running Python 3.11.2, Django 4.2.1, Visual Studio Code**My code is:**
All the from django statements below have sqiggly error marks

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from users import views as user_views
```

**My pip list in my virtual environment is:**

```
asgiref             3.6.0
Django              4.2.1
django-crispy-forms 1.14.0
Pillow              9.4.0
pip                 23.1.2
setuptools          58.1.0
sqlparse            0.4.2
tzdata              2022.1
```

Comment: have you selected the rigth python interpreter in vscode? try `ctrl+shift+p`  and then type `Python: Select Interpreter`

Comment: Yes I selected the interpreter that was recommended by vscode which contains my virtual environment.

Comment: How do I add a screenshot?